# Unable to move files after batch migration

Tags: windows, batch-file

I migrated a batch job from Windows Server 2012 to a Windows Server 2019 VM. It worked on the legacy server but not working on the newly setup virtual machine for some reason...I'm trying to automate the move of all files from a shared network drive locally to the server. The service account that's used to trigger this job via Task Scheduler has full permissions to that location.

```
move /y "\\example.com\europe\Department\EN\Shared Folder\*" "C:\Temp\QUANTITIES"
```

Any ideas why? The batch job simply gets stuck executing even when I run it with my own a-account.

Comment: Can it have something to do with white space in the path? I'm using quotation marks "" around the full path already.

Comment: I'd suggest that your code would attempt to do the move if the destination directory existed, but if that directory was missing, it would move each file in the source over a new **FILE** with the name of the supposed destination directory. Your source data may have been emptied is this second situation exists. I'd extend the destination with `\*`, and `xcopy` the files rather than `move`ing them.